# How to make button edges transparent

Tags: winapi

After working for many years with Borland VCL, Windows Forms and WPF, I'm back to the basics trying to make a small and simple Win32 API application.

I have a bitmap image (not a solid color) at the background of the window, which is basically added by:

```
hbr = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP_BG)));
```

and at `WM_PAINT`:

```
FillRect(wcd.hdc, &wcd.rcPaint, hbr);
```

I understand that making Static Text appear with transparent background over this image can be done using:

```
SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
```

I tried `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` but it is not working.

The problem I have is the buttons. Their edges remain white, and for example this is what I get on Windows 11:

[image]

What alternative should be used for buttons to make their background transparent, like how `SetBkMode()` works for static texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possibilities is to handle `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` in button's parent procedure. You have brush already created, so the only tricky part is moving its origin.

```
        case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
            {
                // Adjust brush origin so correct part will be rendered under button
                POINT   origin = { 0, 0 };
                RECT    button_rect;
                // window_hwnd is argument received by windows procedure
                // i.e. button's parent
                ClientToScreen( window_hwnd, &origin );
                GetWindowRect( (HWND)lparam, &button_rect );
                SetBrushOrgEx( (HDC)wparam, origin.x - button_rect.left, origin.y - button_rect.top, 0 );
                SetBkMode( (HDC)wparam, TRANSPARENT );
                // Return background brush
                return background_brush;
            }
```

Comment: This is the correct way! The duplicate, which was the reason for my question to be closed was only about Solid Color backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 8 and later, you can give a child control, like a button, the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style, and then use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to specify a transparent color to mask out the areas you don't want visible.

Prior to Windows 8, you will have to create a Region, such as via `CreateRoundRectRgn()`, and then apply it to the child control using `SetWindowRgn()`.